# Pick type by array of string

Tags: javascript, typescript, typing

I have type

```
type User = {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    age: string
}
```

I need a function

```
const result =  fun<User>(['firstName', 'lastName'])
```

I need `result` type is a `User` with picked `firstName` and `lastName`. Is it possible to do with typeScript?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I did not came up with this solution myself so all credits go to "drop-george" guy from github:

```
type User = {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;
}

type ElementType < T extends ReadonlyArray < unknown > > = T extends ReadonlyArray<
  infer ElementType
>
  ? ElementType
  : never

function get<T, K extends (keyof T)[]>(v: T, keys: K): Pick<T, ElementType<K>> {
    return v
}

const user: User = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
const v = get(user, ['a', 'b'])
const {a, b, c} = v // ERROR
const {a: a2, b: b2} = v // OK
const {a: a3} = v // OK
get({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} as User, ['a', 'b', 'otherKey']) // ERROR
```

[Original source](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28046#issuecomment-480516434)

UPD: You can just use `ElementType<K>` instead of `ElementType<typeof keys>`

UPD2: AFAIK if you want to make something like `fun<User>(['firstName', 'lastName'])` the only 2 ways are:

- specify properties you need twice:

```
function get<T, K extends (keyof T)[]>(keys: K): Pick<T, ElementType<K>> {
    // return user
}

const user = get<User, ['firstName', 'lastName']>(['firstName', 'lastName'])
```

- or make a function that returns another function kinda like this:

```
function get<T>(): <K extends (keyof T)[]>(keys: K) => Pick<T, ElementType<K>> {
    return keys => {
        // return user from db
    }
}

const user = get<User>()(['firstName', 'lastName'])
```

Comment: How can I use it something like `get<UserType>(['a', 'b'])` for example `get` it's call to the database or somewhere?

Comment: @RuslanGlaznyov I updated the answer (haven't tested it much though)

Answer (score 0):

I think [Typescript utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) can help you, specifically the `Pick` utility type

```js
type User = {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    age: string
}

type UserName = Pick<User, "firstName" | "lastName">;

const example: UserName = {
  firstName: "mo",
  lastName: "mo",
  age: "mo" // Typescript error
}
```

Comment: Cool but I need to do it dynamically. Pick<User, "firstName" | "lastName">;  depends on ['firstName', 'lastName'] array